# Template vars in Jinja

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2, mysql-python

I want to access to a MySQL DB, retrieve some data, create an HTML document using a template and Jinja2 and later, convert it into PDF using weasyprint.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from weasyprint import HTML
import sys


# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","haritz","haritz","appglass" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = "A BIG SELECT"

try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute("USE myDB;")
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in results:
      cantidad = row[0]
      Fecha_pedido = row[1]
      descripcion = row[2]
      Precio_unitario = row[3]
      Referencia_interna = row[4]
      referencia_proveedor = row[5]
      Unidad_de_medida = row[6]
      razon_social = row[7]
      direccion = row[8]
      Nombre_persona_contacto = row[9]
      # Now print fetched result
      print "env"
      env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
      print "template"
      template = env.get_template("plantilla.html")
      print "template_vars"
      template_vars = { "razonSocial": str(razon_social),
                        "personaContacto": str(Nombre_persona_contacto),
                        "direccion": str(direccion),
                        "numPedido": "AAAAAAAAA",
                        "refExtena": str(referencia_proveedor),
                        "descripcion": str(descripcion),
                        "refInterna": str(Referencia_interna),
                        "cantidad" : str(cantidad),
                        "unid": str(Unidad_de_medida),
                        "costeUnit": str(Precio_unitario),
                        "importe": "0"}

      print "html_out"
      html_out = template.render(template_vars)

      print "write_pdf"
      HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf("Pedido.pdf")
except:
   print "Error: unable to fecth data", sys.exc_info()[0]

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

The output I obtain is the following:

```
env
template
template_vars
html_out
Error: unable to fecth data <type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>
```

If I substitute all template vars by string using "something", it works well. But I need to use the data retrieved from the DB. Any ideas why it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it!
http://blog.rastersoft.com/?p=15 here is the solution.
It's in Spanish, so I'll tell you in a nutshell what the problem was.

MySQL uses Latin1 but Python uses UTF-8. So, I had to convert the tables to utf8 and then connect python to the database using utf8. You can see the commands in the webpage.